# syntax error, unexpected identifier DateTimeZone, expecting variable

Tags: laravel

after updating composer i'm getting this error.

i delete the vendor folder and again install the composer but still have erorr .
Laravel version is 8.75
php version is 8.0.25
could someone help ?
thanks in advance[image]

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: error is in vendor/lcobucci/clock/src/SystemClock.php this file .
and whole project is not working

Comment: show us the code where you're using this datetime?

Comment: for DATE and TIME i'm using CARBON class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after upgrading PHP version from 8.0 to 8.1 issue is resolved

Answer (score 0):

Just install version 2.1.0 of lcobucci/clock

You can install it via composer

```
composer require lcobucci/clock:2.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my case, I was using PHP 8.2 and PHP-FPM 8.0 so I changed php-fpm in the nginx configuration to 8.2 like PHP.

And finally, solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this..**

```
<?php

use DateTime;
use DateTimeZone;

**// Create a new DateTime object with a specific timezone**
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

// Retrieve the current date and time
$currentDateTime = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
dd($currentDateTime);
?>
```

Comment: sorry error isn't in my code 
error is in vendor folder

Comment: Have you tried with, "composer update", "php artisan cache:clear" and "composer dump-autoload"?

Comment: yes and still have same issue

Comment: Try updating the package, composer update lcobucci/clock 
and then 
php artisan cache:clear and 
composer dump-autoload

Comment: still have same issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).